# How to update a postgres/postgis table periodically with multiple data?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have created a postgis table from ***point.shp*** with 5 fields containing **20 records**. Now **I want to populate the table with another 150 records keeping the previous 20 records so that the total records count reach 170**.

I have tried 'QGIS to Postgis shp loader (SPIT - Shape to PG Import Tool)' and also 'Postgis shapefile & DBF loader' but **in both cases the tools are asking to overwrite the previous records in the table.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it:

- Import the new shapefile to PostGIS as separate table, then do

  INSERT INTO tablemain SELECT * FROM tablenew;
- Open the PostGIS table and the shapefile in QGIS, edit the POSTGIS table, copy and paste the new features.
- Use shp2pgsql directly on the command line ([you did it before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61917)) and use [option -a](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage).

Comment: For the record: You can also use append mode in the PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export manager (the GUI of shp2pgsql command line tool).